# Generate a DLL which uses protocol-buffers

Tags: c++, dll, protocol-buffers

I am working on a C++ (VS2017) project that uses a protobuf type I created.

However, this project requires a `.dll` of said protobuf type. The `__declspec( dllexport )` in each class declaration are not there by default, and I read online that they can be added by generating the protobuf object with this command line:

```
--cpp_out=dllexport_decl=MY_EXPORT_MACRO:output/directory
```

No one has explained what `MY_EXPORT_MACRO` is or how to define it. When I first generated my protobuf objects I used the most basic line and it worked:

```
protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --cpp_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/my_file.proto
```

What and where is `MY_EXPORT_MACRO` and/or is there another way to make my protobuf files `.dll` compatible?

Answer (score 4):

You know about `__declspec( dllimport )` also, correct?  What's the easiest way to use the same type definition while building the DLL (with `dllexport` annotations) and in DLL clients (with `dllimport` annotations)?

Having a macro to switch the annotation is an extremely common practice in Win32 DLL development of all sorts, not just for protobuf DLLs.

Usually the definition runs like this:

```
#if BUILD_DLLX
#  define DLLX_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  pragma comment('lib', 'dllx.lib')
#  define DLLX_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

And then you would use `--cpp_out=dllexport_decl=DLLX_API:$DST_DIR` so that the generated header files have `DLLX_API` inserted in the right places.  Then build the DLL with `/DBUILD_DLLX` so it exports the types and functions.

Consumers of the DLL can `#include` the exact same header file, and with no `/DBUILD_DLLX` in their project configuration, they'll end up with imports.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer!
Where does this piece of code go though?

Comment: @JessicaChambers: In the header file for the DLL, the file  has all the types and prototypes of functions exported by the DLL.  It should be `#include`d in both the DLL's own code and also in code using the DLL.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, anybody knows if there is a way to say to protoc to add the `#include` that defines `DLLX_API` directly in generated headers ? I looked around but found nothing.

Comment: @gluttony I resolved this by add DLL global define like DLLX_EXPORT=__declspec(dllexport). So, when compile th *pb.cc DLLX_EXPORT will be kown, otherwise use GlobalDefine.h file.